# Unable to implement custom touch listener on google map support fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to handle events apart from the onCamerachange Listener such as knowing the event when the camera is dragged and released. For that I have taken help of a custom touch fragment and touch wrapper to manage the touch events but without success.

Here is my main activity code :

```
public class PickupActivity extends LocationUtils implements OnMapReadyCallback, AddressSearchAdapter.ClickListener {
    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private LatLng center;
    private TextView pickupMarker;
    private LinearLayout markerLayout, addressBox, confirmPickupLayout;
    private EditText address, pincodeText, landmarkText;
    private ImageView currentLocationButton;
    private LatLng latLng, latLng1;
    private JSONArray addressComponents, typesArray;
    String formattedAddress;
    String currentLatitude, currentLongitude;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private SharedPreferenceClass preferenceClass;
    private String pincode, gPlaceId, city, country, state, premise, route, enteredText, pickupLat, pickupLong, currentGplaceId;
    private AddressSearchAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ArrayList<com.packr.classes.Address> addressArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private JSONObject locationObject, geometryObject;
    private com.packr.classes.Address mAddress;
    private int pickupToastVisible = 0;
    private Boolean pickupLocationSet = false, isAddressTextEmpty = false;
    private Button confirmPickupButton;
    private Double a, b, x, y;
    /**
     * Represents a geographical location.
     */
    protected Location mLastLocation;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pickup);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        initialize();
        onClick();
        onSearchTextChanged();

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new MyLinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        mAdapter = new AddressSearchAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this);
        mAdapter.setClickListener(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Set Pickup Location");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        confirmPickupLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.confirmPickupLayout);
        preferenceClass = new SharedPreferenceClass(getApplicationContext());
        pickupMarker = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);
        markerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.locationMarker);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressText);
        currentLocationButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.current_location);
        addressBox = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addressBox);
        pincodeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pincodeText);
        landmarkText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.landmarkText);
        confirmPickupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmPickup);
    }

    public void onClick() {






    }

    public void onSearchTextChanged() {
        address.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() == 0 || s == "") {
                    isAddressTextEmpty = true;
                    if (mRecyclerView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                if (s.length() < 16) {
                    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    enteredText = s.toString().replace(" ", "");
                    if (isAddressTextEmpty) {
                        sendAutocompleteJsonRequest();
                    }
                }
                final List<com.packr.classes.Address> filteredModelList = filter(addressArrayList, s.toString());
                mAdapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
                mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        TouchableMapFragment mFragment;
        mFragment = new TouchableMapFragment();

        new MapStateListener(map,mFragment,this){
            @Override
            public void onMapTouched() {
                // Map touched
                L.m("touched");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMapReleased() {
                // Map released
                L.m("released");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMapUnsettled() {
                // Map unsettled
                L.m("unSettled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMapSettled() {
                // Map settled
                L.m("settled");
            }
        };

        mMap = map;
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
        currentLatitude = preferenceClass.getCurrentLatitude();
        currentLongitude = preferenceClass.getCurrentLongitude();

        a = Double.parseDouble(currentLatitude);
        b = Double.parseDouble(currentLongitude);
        latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(currentLatitude), Double.parseDouble(currentLongitude));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.drawable.current_location_marker)));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLng).zoom(15f).tilt(0).bearing(0).build();
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        address.setText(preferenceClass.getPickupAddress());
        pincodeText.setText(preferenceClass.getPickupPincode());
        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
                if (confirmPickupLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    confirmPickupLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    slideOutTowardsBottom();
                }
                center = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                currentLatitude = String.valueOf(center.latitude);
                currentLongitude = String.valueOf(center.longitude);
                latLng1 = new LatLng(center.latitude, center.longitude);
                Log.e("Coordinates", String.valueOf(center.latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(center.longitude) + latLng1);
                pickupMarker.setText(" Set your Location ");
                if (!pickupLocationSet) {
                    float[] distances = new float[1];
                    Location.distanceBetween(center.latitude, center.longitude, a, b, distances);
                    System.out.println("Distance: " + distances[0]);
                    if (distances[0] > 1000.0) {
                        sendJsonRequest();
                        L.m("called");
                        a = center.latitude;
                        b = center.longitude;
                    }

                }

            }


        });
    }

    public void sendJsonRequest() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getRequestUrl(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                //console test
                parseJsonResponse(jsonObject);
                if (formattedAddress == null) {
                    address.setText("Obtaining Address");
                } else {
                    address.setText(formattedAddress);
                }
                Log.e("error", jsonObject.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError || volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {
                } else if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {
                }
            }
        });
        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                1000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }


    public String getRequestUrl() {

        return KEY_GEOCODE_URL +
                currentLatitude + KEY_COMMA + currentLongitude +
                KEY_SENSOR;
    }


    public void parseJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {
        if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {

            try {
                JSONArray resultArray = response.getJSONArray(KEY_RESULTS);

                if (resultArray.length() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject resultListObject = resultArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        formattedAddress = resultListObject.getString(KEY_FORMATTED_ADDRESS);
                        addressComponents = resultListObject.getJSONArray(KEY_ADDRESS_COMPONENTS);
                        gPlaceId = resultListObject.getString(KEY_PLACE_ID);
                        preferenceClass.savePickupGplaceId(gPlaceId);
                    }
                    if (addressComponents.length() > 0) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < addressComponents.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject addressComponentsObject = addressComponents.getJSONObject(j);
                            typesArray = addressComponentsObject.getJSONArray(KEY_TYPES);
                            if ((typesArray.getString(0)).contentEquals(KEY_POSTAL_CODE)) {
                                if (!addressComponentsObject.isNull(KEY_LONG_NAME))
                                    pincode = addressComponentsObject.getString(KEY_LONG_NAME);
                                pincodeText.setText(pincode);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public String getAutocompleteRequestUrl() {
        return KEY_AUTOCOMPLETE_API.concat(enteredText);
    }

    public void sendAutocompleteJsonRequest() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getAutocompleteRequestUrl(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                parseJSONResponse(jsonObject);
                //Calling the Snackbar
                Log.e("response", jsonObject.toString());
                mAdapter.setAddressArrayList(addressArrayList);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError || volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                    L.T(getApplicationContext(), "Something is wrong with the internet connectivity. Please try again");

                } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    L.T(getApplicationContext(), "Something is wrong with the internet connectivity. Please try again");
                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {
                    L.T(getApplicationContext(), "Something is wrong with the internet connectivity. Please try again");
                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {

                    L.T(getApplicationContext(), "Something is wrong with the internet connectivity. Please try again");
                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {
                    L.T(getApplicationContext(), "Something is wrong with the internet connectivity. Please try again");
                    //TODO
                }

            }
        });
        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                1000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    private void parseJSONResponse(JSONObject response) {
        if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {
            try {
                JSONArray resultArray = response.getJSONArray(KEY_RESULTS);

                if (resultArray.length() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject resultListObject = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        formattedAddress = resultListObject.getString(KEY_FORMATTED_ADDRESS);
                        addressComponents = resultListObject.getJSONArray(KEY_ADDRESS_COMPONENTS);
                        gPlaceId = resultListObject.getString(KEY_PLACE_ID);

                        if (resultListObject.has(KEY_LOCATION) && !(resultListObject.isNull(KEY_LOCATION))) {
                            locationObject = resultListObject.getJSONObject(KEY_LOCATION);
                            if (locationObject.has(KEY_LATITUDE) && !(locationObject.isNull(KEY_LATITUDE))) {
                                currentLatitude = locationObject.getString(KEY_LATITUDE);
                            }
                            if (locationObject.has(KEY_LONGITUDE) && !(locationObject.isNull(KEY_LONGITUDE))) {
                                currentLongitude = locationObject.getString(KEY_LONGITUDE);
                            }
                        }

                        if ((resultListObject.has(KEY_GEOMETRY)) && !(resultListObject.isNull(KEY_GEOMETRY))) {
                            geometryObject = resultListObject.getJSONObject(KEY_GEOMETRY);
                            if (geometryObject.has(KEY_LOCATION) && !(geometryObject.isNull(KEY_LOCATION))) {
                                locationObject = geometryObject.getJSONObject(KEY_LOCATION);
                                if (locationObject.has(KEY_LATITUDE) && !(locationObject.isNull(KEY_LATITUDE))) {
                                    currentLatitude = locationObject.getString(KEY_LATITUDE);
                                }
                                if (locationObject.has(KEY_LONGITUDE) && !(locationObject.isNull(KEY_LONGITUDE))) {
                                    currentLongitude = locationObject.getString(KEY_LONGITUDE);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (addressComponents.length() > 0) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < addressComponents.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject addressComponentsObject = addressComponents.getJSONObject(j);
                                typesArray = addressComponentsObject.getJSONArray(KEY_TYPES);
                                if ((typesArray.getString(0)).contentEquals(KEY_CITY)) {
                                    if (!addressComponentsObject.isNull(KEY_LONG_NAME))
                                        city = addressComponentsObject.getString(KEY_LONG_NAME);
                                } else if ((typesArray.getString(0)).contentEquals(KEY_COUNTRY)) {
                                    if (!addressComponentsObject.isNull(KEY_LONG_NAME))
                                        country = addressComponentsObject.getString(KEY_LONG_NAME);
                                } else if ((typesArray.getString(0)).contentEquals(KEY_STATE)) {
                                    if (!addressComponentsObject.isNull(KEY_LONG_NAME))
                                        state = addressComponentsObject.getString(KEY_LONG_NAME);
                                } else if ((typesArray.getString(0)).contentEquals(KEY_POSTAL_CODE)) {
                                    if (!addressComponentsObject.isNull(KEY_LONG_NAME))
                                        pincode = addressComponentsObject.getString(KEY_LONG_NAME);
                                } else if ((typesArray.getString(0)).contentEquals(KEY_PREMISE)) {
                                    premise = addressComponentsObject.getString(KEY_LONG_NAME);
                                } else if ((typesArray.getString(0)).contentEquals(KEY_ROUTE)) {
                                    route = addressComponentsObject.getString(KEY_LONG_NAME);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (country.contentEquals("India") && city.contentEquals("Kolkata")) {
                            mAddress = new com.packr.classes.Address();
                            mAddress.setFormattedAddress(formattedAddress);
                            mAddress.setCity(city);
                            mAddress.setCountry(country);
                            mAddress.setPincode(pincode);
                            mAddress.setState(state);
                            mAddress.setStreet(premise);
                            mAddress.setRoute(route);
                            mAddress.setLatitude(currentLatitude);
                            mAddress.setLongitude(currentLongitude);
                            mAddress.setGplaceId(gPlaceId);
                            addressArrayList.add(mAddress);
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private List<com.packr.classes.Address> filter(List<com.packr.classes.Address> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<com.packr.classes.Address> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (com.packr.classes.Address model : models) {
            final String text = model.getFormattedAddress().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }


    public void slideInFromBottom() {

        Animation tvAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom);
        confirmPickupLayout.startAnimation(tvAnim);

    }

    public void slideOutTowardsBottom() {

        Animation tvAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom);
        confirmPickupLayout.startAnimation(tvAnim);

    }
// to check whether location services are enable or not

    public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
        int locationMode = 0;
        String locationProviders;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            try {
                locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

            } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;

        } else {
            locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
        hideKeyboard();
        confirmPickupLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        slideInFromBottom();
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pickupLat = addressArrayList.get(position).getLatitude();
        pickupLong = addressArrayList.get(position).getLongitude();
        preferenceClass.savePickupLatitude(currentLatitude);
        preferenceClass.savePickupLongitude(currentLongitude);
        String pincode = addressArrayList.get(position).getPincode();
        currentGplaceId = addressArrayList.get(position).getGplaceId();
        preferenceClass.savePickupGplaceId(currentGplaceId);
        latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(pickupLat), Double.parseDouble(pickupLong));
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLng).zoom(15f).tilt(0).bearing(0).build();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        address.setText(formattedAddress);
        if (pincode != null) {
            pincodeText.setText(pincode);
        }

    }

    public Boolean validationCheck() {
        if (address.getText().length() == 0) {
            L.t(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide a pickup address");
        } else if (pincodeText.getText().length() != 6) {
            L.t(getApplicationContext(), "Pincode must contain 6 digits");
        } else if (landmarkText.getText().length() == 0) {
            L.t(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide a landmark");
        } else return true;
        return false;
    }


    private void hideKeyboard() {
        // Check if no view has focus:
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the code for the custom Touch fragement. I have extended MapSupportFragment

```
public class TouchableMapFragment extends MapFragment {

    private View mOriginalContentView;
    private TouchableWrapper mTouchView;

    public void setTouchListener(TouchableWrapper.OnTouchListener onTouchListener) {
        mTouchView.setTouchListener(onTouchListener);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        L.m("called");
        mOriginalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent,
                savedInstanceState);


        mTouchView = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
        mTouchView.addView(mOriginalContentView);


        return mTouchView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return mOriginalContentView;
    }


}
```

Here is the code for the touchWrapper

```
public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {


    public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


    public void setTouchListener(OnTouchListener onTouchListener) {
        this.onTouchListener = onTouchListener;
    }


    private OnTouchListener onTouchListener;


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                onTouchListener.onTouch();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                onTouchListener.onRelease();
                break;
        }


        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }


    public interface OnTouchListener {
        void onTouch();
        void onRelease();
    }
}
```

Please help.